# how to add data into php mysql from html sqlite data base

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have sqlite data base which works fine adds data and also shows but i want to add these all data into mysql table in php any way how to add all these data in my sql table.

Below is the show function which i call in hmtl file to show records from data base but how to add these in php mysql table. Normally we add using post and send variables but how to send this type of data.

Table columns in mysql table are

ID,UserName,UserEmailAddress,Score and Category

```
function showRecords() // Function For Retrive data from Database Display records as list

{

    $("#results").html('')

    db.transaction(function (tx) {

        tx.executeSql(selectAllStatement, [], function (tx, result) {

            dataset = result.rows;



            for (var i = 0, item = null; i < dataset.length; i++) {



                item = dataset.item(i);
                mycars[i] = item['username'];
                emails[i] = item['useremail'];
                risklevel[i] = item['third'];
                catagory[i] = item['fourth'];


                totalCount=dataset.length;
                var linkeditdelete = '<li>' + item['username'] + ' , ' + item['useremail'] + ' , ' + item['third'] + ', ' + item['fourth'] + '   ' + '<a href="#" onclick="loadRecord(' + i + ');">edit</a>' + '    ' +

                '<a href="#" onclick="deleteRecord(' + item['id'] + ');">delete</a></li>';

                $("#results").append(linkeditdelete);


            }
            showUsername();

        });

    });
```